# Displaying list of foreign key values Asp Net Web Api

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

[JsonError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKIpZ.png)

Working on my Gym managment application I've encountered with displaying collection of data related to Client model.

The problem is related to following models:

```
public class Client
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int CardId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string PersonalInfo => "ID: " + CardId + ": " + Name + " " + Surname;

    public int? GymEntries { get; set; }
    public int? MartialArtsEntries { get; set; }

    public int? GymEntriesLeft { get; set; }
    public int? MartialArtsEntriesLeft { get; set; }

    public DateTime? ClientJoined { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SubscriptionExpires { get; set; }

    public int? SubscriptionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Subscription Subscription { get; set; }

    public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
}


public class Payment
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }

    public int? SubscriptionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Subscription Subscription { get; set; }

    public int CashRegistered { get; set; }
    public string AdditionalInformation { get; set; }

    public DateTime? PaymentRegistered { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SubscriptionExpires { get; set; }

}
```

Everything works fine, until I want my Client controller, when given get/id request, to return all Client data including all payments related to client id from Payment. Json result in Postman doesn't return proper format, it misses payments list.

That's the way I try to do that in my Controller

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Client>> GetClient(int id)
{
   var client = await _context.Client.FindAsync(id);
   var subscription = await _context.Subscription.FindAsync(client.SubscriptionId); 
   var payments = await _context.Payment.Where(p => p.Client == client).ToListAsync();

   client.Subscription = subscription;
   client.Payments = payments;

   if (client == null)
   {
       return NotFound();
   }

   if (client.IsDeleted == true)
   {
       return NotFound();
   }

   return client;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that:

```
var payments = await _context.Payment.Where(p => p.ClientId == client.Id).ToListAsync();
```

You should use your `Id`'s to select entities but not entire entities.

**UPD:**

Try to set attribute `[JsonIgnore]` on `public virtual Client Client { get; set; }` in your `Payment` class. To prevent json serializer from endless loop.

Also you can stop Self referencing loop due to the proxies while you converting the entity to JSON as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(
            options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        );

    ...
}
```

Comment: Still the same. Error ;(

Comment: I think that entity framework tries to load your referenced entity, so that you have bad format. I've updated my answer, try that.

Comment: Oh man! Thanks a lot [JsonIgnore] solved the problem entirely.